# Tabbar не прогружается

Tags: swift, storyboard

При попытке показать TabBar ошибок не возникает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске приложения виден только Navigation Bar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: identifier установлен верно

Comment: прикрепите скриншот сториборд, а код прикрепите в виде текста а не картинки

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в том, что нужно создать TabBarController и добавить туда ViewController

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           
        let viewController = ViewController()
    
        viewControllers = [createNavigationController(rootViewController: viewController,
                                                      title: "ViewController",
                                                      image: UIImage(systemName: "star")!)]
    }

    private func createNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
    
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        navigationVC.tabBarItem.title = title
        navigationVC.tabBarItem.image = image

        return navigationVC
    }
}
```